# Get data from table celle

Tags: javascript

i have a table and i want the data from the cells to be printed onto a input field when i click the a specific table cell using the "onclick" command. i was thinking about getdocumentbyid or something like that

greet

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a unique ID for each cell, then calling `document.getElementById("<id>").innerHTML` to get the contents?

Or, better yet, if the `onClick` event is for the same element you want to get the contents of, you won't need an ID; you should be able to just use `this.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is have a single event handler on the table or table row to handle the onclicks for you, rather than applying an `onclick` handler to each cell.  The onclick event will bubble from the TD elements up to the table element for which the handler will fire.  This is called delegation.

An example:

```
// Get a handle to the input box
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Set up the onclick event for the table
document.getElementById("mytable").onclick = function (evt) {
    // window.event for IE, evt argument for others
    var evt = evt || window.event;
    // Get the element the event originated from
    var el  = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    // If the element's tagName is <TD>, set the text of the input
    if (el.tagName == "TD")
        // innerText for IE, textContent for others
        myInput.value = "textContent" in el ? el.textContent : el.innerText;
}
```

If you just want it for a specific row, set the onclick event for that row instead.